# How can I access my Flask API within a docker container?

Tags: docker, flask

I have set up a Flask API to try and host my TensorFlow model online which I'm using for a mobile app - I have created a docker image with all of the correct imports and whenever I run the docker container the terminal shows this but I can't see it on these URLs:

- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
- Running on http://172.17.0.3:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is listening on port 5000.  The second `docker run -p` port number must match this port.  The two port numbers don't need to match each other.  So, to map port 5001 on the host to port 5000 in the container, you'd use

```bash
#             host port (your choice)
#                vvvv
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 nea-api
#                     ^^^^
#               container port (matches server process's port)
```